# Using BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential in a partial (medium) trust enviroment

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have an application which consumes a WCF web service, i log in to said service using credentials supplied by the company who maintain the service.

This is the code I created for binding the service.
I used svcutil.exe to generate a ClientSearchService.cs file and imported it into the project

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IClientSearch";
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
myBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
myBinding.MaxBufferSize = 524288;
myBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 524288;
myBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
myBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 524288;
myBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 524288;
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceEndPointAddress);
ClientSearchClient myClient = new ClientSearchClient(myBinding, endPointAddress);

myClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
myClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = userPass;

var request = new schemas.advancedcheck.co.uk.DriverChecksRequest();
request.FromDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
request.ToDate = DateTime.Now;
var response = myClient.GetDriverChecks(request);
```

If i execute this in a full trust environment i have no issues and the data I expect to see is returned successfully, however, where the code will be hosted will be a partial trust enviroment and when ran in a partial trust enviroment it throws this error:

`The Binding with name BasicHttpBinding_IClientSearch failed validation because it contains a BindingElement with type System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement which is not supported in partial trust. Consider using BasicHttpBinding or WSHttpBinding, or hosting your application in a full-trust environment.`

is there another method i can use to consume this web service in a partial trust enviroment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a web service with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 online plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886049/using-a-web-service-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-online-plugin)

Comment: Reposting the same question a day later is unlikely to get a better response.

Comment: The last question seemed too CRM specific in my mind when it didn't need to be.